# Retrieving Array - Key Value pair - Cannot read property 'DisplayName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, sharepoint-2013

I'm having some issue with pulling information out of an array, and I feel like I'm doing something, but just not really sure what. What I'm attempting to do is pull user information into a page from SharePoint user information. When checking the array in the Chrome debugging window, this shows the information as expected.

However, when attempting to call the array with the key, it does not appear to work and throws the error

> Cannot read property 'DisplayName' of undefined

The goal of the code is to pull a SharePoint list, via REST, load it into an Array, for use later in the code vs trying to pull the SharePoint list each time. I have done something similar for other REST calls, and looped through the array using `$.each` and matching the ID, however in this case only one array set is pulled.

I have attempted to call the items as

```
UserProfileBase[0][0]['DisplayName']
UserProfileBase[0]['DisplayName']
UserProfileBase[0][0].DisplayName
UserProfileBase[0].DisplayName
UserProfileBase[""0""][""0""].DisplayName
UserProfileBase[""0""][""0""].['DisplayName']
```

The array is built using this inside of a AJAX call to a REST point in a SharePoint site.

```
UserProfileBase= ([{UserId : xAccountName,DisplayName:xDisplayName,Email:xEmail, Title: xTitle}]);
```

but I have also tried

```
UserProfileBase= ([{UserId : xAccountName,DisplayName:xDisplayName,Email:xEmail, Title: xTitle}]);
```

The expected output, would be to pull a single item from the array for display on a page in SharePoint. The items will all be strings.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed!

Comment: Can you provide the output of `console.log(UserProfileBase)` ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/38k71bhf/

Comment: Did you debug your code using Browser F12 tools and inspected the variables?

Comment: In Chrome Debugger when calling the array UserProfileBase I get:

`[{…}]
0: {UserId: "123456", DisplayName: "LastName, FirstName", Email: "Email@Address", Title: "x\123456"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`


However when using console.log() i get:

`[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)` @JeroenHeier @Dahou

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz the fiddle is kind of what i'm doing, except it would only be one return vs multiples, and the value items are variables from the REST call. I did try the `UserProfileBase[ 0 ]['DisplayName'] ` thinking that maybe the additional spacing might make a difference, however the same error was returned.

Comment: When using `UserProfileBase= ([{...}]);` console.log(UserProfileBase) returns empty, but when using `UserProfileBase.push([{...}]);` console.log(UserProfileBase) returns the array as expected, but the error still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, the issue is related to AJAX. I was attempting to retrieve the information before the call completed.